# RHEL 6.4: Cannot Update via Terminal

Tags: updates, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I have a RHEL 6.4 server and I cannot use the `yum` command from within an SSH connection. If I execute any `yum` command (`yum update`, `yum install`, `yum clean all`) I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
```

It stays there forever, no matter how long I leave it. Nothing else ever appears. The GUI is not accessible, so I cannot use the package manager. I've tried clearing the db files. Our subscription is still current. We are using the default RHEL repositories, no third party repositories have been added.

Comment: Can you see a lot of CPU or HDD usage when this happens?

Comment: Is there something that needs a GUI? It sounds like a problem due to the lack of X. Does `yum` have a pop up or something when not run as root? Do any windows appear when you run this locally?

Comment: @lopsided98: There is no CPU, HDD, or network access whatsoever.

@ terdon: This is what I'm getting when using the terminal, not X. I was just mentioning that X is not an option right now so I can't use the GUI equivalent

Comment: Is there another yum process running which would cause follow-on yum commands to wait for the itto complete?